# SQL server replace in where clause

Tags: sql-server, string, replace, where-clause

Let's say we got a Table.
This Table has a column (varchar) for each student code .
I want to search many students base on a filter i have set.

For example i got a question field(varchar) that the user insert
the codes seperated with comma ,such as `000012,000014,000058`.

The question field returns me the value like that `'000012,000014,000058'`
The SQL query implements the question field that way 
`Select * from Students where code  in ( '000012,000014,000058')`

I have to change the value to: `('000012','000014','000058')`
so using the replace function  `REPLACE(CHAR(39)+'000012,000014,000058'+CHAR(39),',',CHAR(39)+','+CHAR(39))`
i'm trying this one

```
Select * 
from students 
where code in (REPLACE(CHAR(39)+'000012,000014,000058'+CHAR(39),',',CHAR(39)+','+CHAR(39)))
```

But still not working.

Any Ideas?

Comment: If I understand it right your only problem is the posting data. So before the query and IF `code` field is numeric, just replace the `'` for nothing and your query would yield to `code in ( 000012,000014,000058)` wich will work just fine. This, of course, is a workaround.

Comment: mayde i was not clear. My db is properly design.
Each Record of code column has only one value.
The user types in a question field on front end the codes of the students seperated with comma 00012,00058 in order to see infos about the students. 
So i have to make the sql query select * from students where code in ('00012','00058')

Comment: @JorgeCampos yes you are right , if the code was numeric it's fine
but the code column is varchar

Comment: I'm confused - What is your front end? Does the question field populate a table in your database or does it build a sql query?

Answer (score 1):

Your `REPLACE(...` returns a string and what you need is table-like something. There are a lot of methods to split a string (varchar) to a table. This is just one of them.

```
declare @ids varchar(100)='000012,000014,000058'
declare @x xml='<x>'+replace(@ids,',','</x><x>')+'</x>'
select * from students
where code in (
select t.x.value('.[1]','varchar(10)')
from @x.nodes('x') t(x)
)
```

Comment: if the list of codes is user-provided you may want to escape (html encode) the five special xml chars: `& > < ' "`

Answer (score 0):

As jpw says, having comma delimited values in a cell violates first normal form and so SQL's ability to query has already been undermined. What you can do in cases like this is first get back to normal form, then proceed as normal:

If you have SQL Server 2016 you can use string_split with cross apply to split the cells back into rows ([here's a backwards compatible string_split for earlier versions](https://gist.github.com/gfody/9443629f893ba4577524)), e.g:

```
select s.* from students s cross apply string_split(code, ',')
where value in ('000012','000014','000058')
```

..alternatively if you don't have 2016 and don't want to add the string_split function, you can use .nodes as in Alex's answer like so:

```
select s.* from students s cross apply
(select convert(xml, '<x>' + replace(code, ',', '</x><x>') + '</x>')) a(code_xml)
cross apply code_xml.nodes('*') x(n)
where n.value('.','varchar(20)') in ('000012','000014','000058')
```

--- edit ---

Just noticed in comments you state that the database cell does not include comma delimited values - in this case Alex's answer is appropriate.